# useEffect React for function checkSession

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks

At first it worked, but then it stopped.The problem is that the same action is performed on the server 4 times, apparently this is due to useEffect

My component:

```
function TableComp() {
  const session = useCheckCookieToken()
  return (
    session !== null ?
      <>
        <Menu />
        <AddService />
        <DataTable />
      </>
      :
      <Navigate to="/" />
  )
}
```

My service function:

```
async function useCheckCookieToken() {
  const [session, setSession] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
      async function sessionPost() {
        const res = await fetch(`/api/checkCookie`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
        })
        if (res.ok) {
          const result = await res.json()
          setSession(result)
        }
      }
      sessionPost()
      return () => { console.log('unmount') }
  }, [])
  return session
}

module.exports = {
  useCheckCookieToken
}
```

My API:

I tracked that in the interval highlighted in the screenshot from 97 to 101 lines, the same action is triggered 4 times, apparently the problem is related to the problem of mounting
[image]

Comment: Is the `useCheckCookieToken` hook used in multiple components (places)? Is the `TableComp` component used in multiple places?

The server code seems incomplete. When the `session` is found, I've noticed it's just returned. Shouldn't a response be sent, instead?

Comment: TableComp used once , it's like a new page.useCheckCookieToken it is used once when switching on each new page from / to /table.